# Formula that will repeat number X times and increased by a counter

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have the following problem: I need to repeat a given number, say 3 times.  I then need to repeat the next number the same amount of times.  So I need a formula to print, for instance, 111, 222, 333, 444 etc. each on a different row.  Can this be done?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to happen after 999?

Comment: that's actually correct. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

So something like:

```
A1 =REPT(1,3)      // Initial number set to 1, repeated 3 times to give 111
A2 =REPT(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)/3)+1,3)
A3 =REPT(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)/3)+1,3)
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

Still not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish.  But in the scenario where you want to see:

111,222,...,101010,111111,...,999999,100100100,101101101,...

You could just copy this formula down the column:

> `=REPT(ROW(),3)`

ROW() returns the current row, so you might have to do a little math to make it produce your number.  I.e. if you want "111" to appear in row #2, "=REPT(ROW()-1,3)"

If that's not what you're looking for, please be more explicit.

Comment: Hi.  What I was looking for was a number to be printed three times, on three different rows, and then be the number be increased by one and once again printed on three different lines. So I would want the number 1 to be in A1, A2, and A3.  Then 2 in A4, A5, A6, then 3 in A7 A8 and A9

Comment: Okay... so "=ROW()" goes in the first 3x3 block of your worksheet, giving you 3 columns of a single number that increments in each row.

Comment: Correction... I think what you want is to copy this down the column: "=INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1"

Answer (score 1):

Try on A1 `=REPT(1+FLOOR(COLUMN()-1,3)/3,3)` and then drag to all other columns... hopefully this is what you wanted if I understood correctly from the comments.